# Both navigation bars are combined

Tags: navigation, current-navigation

So I'm not sure how I managed to mess this up... But somehow turning on
SharePoint Server Publishing and changing itemstyle.xsl made both of my nav bars combine into one top nav bar. Can I return them to two separate bars? One on the left and the other on top? In the image below you can see that the whole left nav bar was moved to the top and the home button is missing[image]

Answer (score 0):

To manage navigation for a SharePoint site, you must have the Full Control or Design permission level for the site. You have one of these permission levels if you can access the Sites Settings page for the site and you see the Navigation command under Look and Feel (**on non-publishing sites, you will see the Quick Launch and Top link bar commands under Look and Feel instead of Navigation**).

1. To go to the Site Navigation Settings page, do one of the following:

   - On the Site Actions menu, click Site Settings.
   - On the Site Actions menu, point to Site Settings, and then click Modify All Site Settings.
2. In the Look and Feel column, click Navigation.

**Note:** The Navigation command appears under Look and Feel only if the publishing features are enabled for your site and you have the Full Control or Design permission level.

Comment: Is above answer helps you to arrange the navigation properly?

Comment: I still couldn't find the fix to this, the navigation settings didn't change the bar back to its original position

Comment: What did you tried till date?

Comment: Well what I thought the problem was initially was the server publishing feature. So I turned that back off and it didn't fix it. In the navigation page, the current navigation and global both have links under them, but the current navigation is displaying on top for some reason, and the global navigation is nowhere to be seen